# What package do I use to write angular bracket symbols in Latex?

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to express an unordered m-tuple (or symmetric m-tuple) as < a_1,...,a_m >. So while writing I used greater and less than symbols ( `>',` <' )from the keyboard but that is causing some spacing problems. So I looked up the commands (on tug.ctan.org/info/symbols) for angular brackets and they are \lAngle, \rAngle etc. But these are not working because I am using ams symb. Could anybody tell me what are the appropriate packages to use? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are probably better off asking this question at [tex.se], but `\langle` and `\rangle` produce the correct symbols.  You might need one of the AMS packages for this, but I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like it's a capitalization issue. No special package is required for `\langle` $\langle$ and `\rangle` $\rangle$.

Comment: I've got codes that $\langle,\rangle,\langle$/As I go writing merrily along.

Comment: Thanks! That solves it.